# How to set atom editor to main editor

Tags: 16.04, error-handling, editor, atom

i have been searching about this topic. But i can find it. I want to set atom to my `$EDITOR` on the terminal.I tried `nikola new_post -e` on the terminal. But i am keep getting this error `ERROR: new_post: $EDITOR not set, cannot edit the post.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the EDITOR variable as follows in Terminal

```
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/atom"
```

If you want that as a permanent setting consider adding it to your `~/.bashrc` and reload the updated  `.bashrc` via `source ~/.bashrc.`